# Combinatorial problem. No. of combination with repetition.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have little task to solve. Problem is that I have 29 balls and I must distribute them into 5 boxes. An additional requirement is that each box can have max 7 balls. I think that this problem represent number of combination with repetiton, but this additional requirement makes me problem.

Comment: do you know generating functions?

Comment: If each box can hold no more than $7$ balls then you can't put $29$ balls in them.

Comment: @gt6989b well i have material , now i'm starting to learn them,are we solving this problem with generating functions?

Comment: @lulu i don't have to put 7 balls in every box, i need to find number of combination of possible distribution, one box can have non balls other two can have 7 etc...

Comment: I don't understand.  If you put the maximum of $7$ in each box then you have only used $28$ balls.  You can't put all $29$ in.  Or are you saying that you don't have to use all $29$ balls?

Comment: @  gt6989b i thought that this is normal combination problem with one requirement...:/

Comment: @  lulu  sorry lulu i have 5 boxes not 4. Lapsus calami.

Comment: No problem.  Are the boxes distinguishable?  That is, is the distribution $\{1,7,7,7,7\}$ different from the distribution $\{7,1,7,7,7\}$?

Comment: No, they aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating functions are a good method here, but perhaps they are overkill.  Direct enumeration is straight forward.  Work from the number of $7's$ in the distribution:

I.  Four $7's$.  Then the fifth box must have $1$ so there is $\fbox {1}$

II. Three $7's$  Then the other two must add to $8$ without using a $7$.  We could have $(2,6),(3,5),(4,4)$ so $\fbox {3}$

III.Two $7's$. Then the other three must add to $15$ without using a $7$.  Hence we could have $(3,6,6),(4,5,6), (5,5,5)$ so again $\fbox {3}$

IV.  One $7$.  Then the other four must add to $22$ without using a $7$.  Hence we could have $(4,6,6,6),(5,5,6,6)$ so $\fbox {2}$

V.  No $7's$ We must have $(5,6,6,6,6)$ so $\fbox {1}$

Summing we get: $\fbox {1+3+3+2+1=10}$

Note:  While straight forward, the above method is a bit error prone (it is easy to overlook a case or two).  I recommend going over it.

Added:  as a reference for the generating function method, I recommend https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/partitions.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much @lulu. At the moment i'm reading about generating functions and they seem so complicated. In general in this combinatoric everytihng look identical, variations combinations with or without repetition but everything is different. Thanks again. :D

Comment: Generating functions are quite powerful, but I agree they take some getting used to.  I think it's good to work on straight enumerations at the same time...if nothing else, it gives an alternate method you can use to check your work!

Answer (score 0):

As lulu has said, this method can be quite error prone.
My strategy to cut down such errors is to count down from the highest "number"

$77771,\; 77762,\; 77753,\; 77744,\; 77663,\; 77654,\; 77555,\; 76663,\; 76654,\; 66665$